# The topology service is not available in the farm in SharePoint 2016

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, 2016, spservices, topology

I have installed the SP2016 on server but when I run the wizard all the services are got created except search. I got error when I clicked on search service"`The topology service is not available in the farm.`" 
After lots of search I have found that I don't have proxy service for `Application Discovery and Load Balancer Service Application`. I have also searched in log file to find something suspicious and getting below error:

```
Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException: The topology service is not available in the farm.    at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPTopologyWebServiceApplication.GetDynamicUri()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPTopologyWebServiceApplication.get_Uri()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages.ServiceApplicationPublishPage.OnLoad(EventArgs e)     at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()     at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) f1850d9e-46c9-8034-8adb-6889a11e1c71
```

This shows topology is not avaible in the farm, can someone guide me what does this mean and how to fix this OR how can I generate the proxy for Load Balancer service.

Comment: Is it stand-alone minrole?

Comment: I have WFE where CA is installed and services are configured and used SQL server for its DB.

Comment: What are all the services configured ? Did you configure Search services using CA?

Comment: I have configured it thru Configuration wizard as well as PowerShell both.
all the other services are configured thru wizard only.

Comment: Finally I have fixed the problem by re-installing the SP.
Earlier I specified the server role as 'Font-end', now this time I selected it as 'Single server farm' and this helps me to fix the problem.
ref: https://blog.devoworx.net/2015/09/03/install-sharepoint-2016-preview-single-server-farm/